# what is wrong with using foreach in Neo4j this way?

Tags: neo4j

I want to create nodes and relationships using foreach. for each m create two node p whom m [Knows]:

```
start n=node(1) 
foreach(i in range(1,2): 
       create (m{id:i}) 
       foreach(j in range(1,2): 
              create (p{name:i,id:j}), 
              (m)-[:knows]->(p)
       )
);
```

there is no syntax error, but it creates more nodes than I expected. The following is all nodes that are created:

```
==> | Node[27]{id:1}              |
==> | Node[28]{name:1,id:1}       |
==> | Node[29]{name:1,id:2}       |
==> | Node[30]{name:1,id:1}       |
==> | Node[31]{}                  |
==> | Node[32]{name:1,id:2}       |
==> | Node[33]{}                  |
==> | Node[34]{id:2}              |
==> | Node[35]{name:2,id:1}       |
==> | Node[36]{name:2,id:2}       |
==> | Node[37]{name:2,id:1}       |
==> | Node[38]{}                  |
==> | Node[39]{name:2,id:2}       |
==> | Node[40]{}                  |
```

how these commands create node(30-33) and node(37-40)?  and the relationships among them are:

```
(31)-[:knows]->(30)
(33)-[:knows]->(32)
(38)-[:knows]->(37)
(40)-[:knows]->(39)
```

Please help me out. Great Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not very clear to me ! However I think you stumbled upon an "undocumented feature" as the foreach operator doesn't seem to be dedicated to creation operations, but only mutating ones

Comment: Agree. I just want to use nested foreach statements to generate nodes and relationships. Here, I want to create some nodes (m),  for each m I want to create lots of node p whom m [Knows]. Is there another way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what was wrong with your query, but this seems to work as expected in 2.0.0. Note, I do not have a node

```
CREATE (n:XX)
FOREACH (i in range(1,2) |
    CREATE (m:XX {id:i}),
    (m)-[:PARENT]->(n)
    FOREACH (j in range(3,4)|
        CREATE (p:XX {name:i, id:j}),
        (m)-[:KNOWS]->(p)
    )
)
RETURN n--()--()
```

I modified this a bit to create a new node as the root, and the syntax has changed since 1x, so `FOREACH` now uses pipe `|`. Only the appropriate nodes are created with no blank nodes like you see in your example. Maybe this was a bug that has since been fixed?